# Start command with new process group id golang

Tags: macos, go, process

I'm starting a command and storing its PID with the intention of killing it later on. As the process is started with the command creates sub processes, I have to send the kill signal to all process group using

```
syscall.Kill(-pid, syscall.SIGINT)
```

This works fine in Linux but not on MacOS. The reason is that, on the mac when command starts it doesn't create it with a different process group, so sending signal to `-pid` is failing. (If I send the signal to `pid`, it doesn't kill the child processes)

I tried starting the command with the following flags as well, but it doesn't help on MacOS.

```
command := exec.Command(commandName, arg...)
command.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true, Pgid: 0}
```

The newly started process gets the group id of the terminal session where the go executable is running instead of new process group id. Is there a way to start a new process group in MacOS?

Comment: That should work as expected. Are you certain the child processes aren't setting their own PGIDs; or maybe even ignoring SIGINT? Does ps show that they all have the same PGID?

Comment: I'm certain. ps shows. If I execute the command in terminal, new process has the pid and pgid same, all the children processes are getting the same pgid as the new process. When I executed the command in go, both the new process and its children has the pgid of the terminal session. (In linux it works as expected though)

Comment: Are any of these process starting in a shell pipeline? It sounds like something else is specifically setting or changing the pgid. You could try setting `Setsid: true` to make sure the process is starting in a new session.

Comment: It sets the process group id correctly with `Setsid: true` and it's all fine. I thought this is exactly what `Setpgid` is supposed to do. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @rosencreuz I stumbled upon the same problem. Did you find an explanation?